# The (&(objectCategory=user)(|(CN=)(sAMAccountName=))) search filter is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

> The (&(objectCategory=user)(|(CN=)(sAMAccountName=))) search filter is
>   invalid.

Can someone tell me under what circumstances does this error show up ?

I am trying to publish my web application through Visual Studio. I runs fine on the local host but gives this error after publishing.

```
 public static string[] ldapUserQuery(string userName, string[] desiredProps)
    {
        //  Establishes path for query. In this case sap.corp
        string queryPath = "LDAP://DC=SAP,DC=CORP";

        //  Used to establish desiredProps from within the function, but now it can be passed in.
        //  This was kept in here as an example of what the desiredProps should look like when
        //  passing it in.
        //
        //  Desired pros are the LDAP attributes to be returned.
        /*
            string[] desiredProps = new string[]
            {
                //"givenName",    //  first name
                //"sn",           //  last name
                //"mail"          //  email
            };
        */

        //  establishes the proper length of the array to be returned.
        string[] returnVal = new string[desiredProps.Length];

        //  Creates objects for performing the Query.
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry();
        DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        SearchResult result;

        //  dirEntry is used for establishing the connection for the query
        dirEntry.Path = queryPath;
        dirEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

        //  dirSearcher is the query itself.
        dirSearcher.SearchRoot = dirEntry;
        dirSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(|(CN={0})(sAMAccountName={0})))", userName);

        //  executes the query.
        result = dirSearcher.FindOne();

        //  handle the result of the query.
        if (result != null)
        {
            //  if the query was successful, then dig through the returned information
            //  and set found objects that match the desiredProps to the returnVal object.
            for (int i = 0; i < desiredProps.Length; i++)
            {
                //  if the desiredProps has a bad attribute name, just give it the placeholder
                //  and move along.
                if (result.Properties[desiredProps[i]] != null)
                {
                    returnVal[i] = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties[desiredProps[i]].Value.ToString();
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    returnVal[i] = GlobalVars.placeHolder;
                //}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you  authenticated as a domain user?

Comment: no the authentication has been set to windows

Answer (score 5):

`(&(objectCategory=user)(|(CN=)(sAMAccountName=)))` is invalid because it doesn't know what `CN` attribute and `sAMAccountName` attribute you are trying to compare to.

`(&(objectCategory=user)(|(CN=something)(sAMAccountName=someName)))` is valid.  Replace *something* and *someName* by something that meaningful to you.

Comment: dirSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(|(CN={0})(sAMAccountName={0})))", userName); It is already set ! should i share my ldap code here?

Comment: @Pradit You better print out the things that substituted into the string.  I think you might be using some restricted characters.  You need to escape those restricted characters

Comment: Print the filter string to debug console.  It's complaining the filter string.  It must be something wrong set at the filter string